# PayPal agreement_transaction_list empty without changes

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

yesterday 22 march i noticed that my api calls to billing agreement api return the "agreement_transaction_list" object completely empty.
I've no made changes to my code:

```
$params = array('start_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-15 years')), 'end_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days')));

try {
    $result = Agreement::searchTransactions($subscription_agreement_id, $params, $apiContext);
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    error_log($ex->getData());
    echo $ex->getData();
    exit;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    error_log($ex);
    echo $ex;
    exit;
}

echo $result;
```

And the result (same for all customers):

```
{
    "agreement_transaction_list": []
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: You could try a sooner start_date, but otherwise this looks like something you should contact PayPal's support about and provide the full request + response, including the PayPal-Debug-Id HTTP header of the response.  Add logging to the code so you can obtain this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that PayPal has fixed it after ~24 hours.